# Extracting and manipulating data from a multiple interval JList to use in textArea/JOptionPane

Tags: java, arrays, jlist

As the title says, I have a multiple interval selection `JList` and i'm having trouble properly manipulating the data. This is my first time using a `JList` and it's proving difficult for me.

My GUI acts as a ticket ordering interface for a sports team, and the `JList` i'm referring to holds a list of souvenirs customers can order. Since it's a multiple selection `JList`, they can select multiple souvenirs if they so choose.

My issue is extracting the items from the JList and properly printing them to a `JOptionPane` `textArea` window, which acts as a summary for the user's order. Here is a breakdown of my goals/issues:

1. Extracting the souvenirs selected, where the names of the souvenirs are stored in a `String[]` array
2. Matching a parallel array of prices, stored in a `Double[]` array
3. Using the proper methods from the JList event handler to then print the data to the `textArea` summary
4. Eliminating duplicates of souvenirs that seem to appear when I try and print the data to the `textArea`

Here is the creation of my JList:

```
souvenirList = new JList(itemNames); //itemNames is an array of Strings[] for souvenirs
souvenirList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
souvenirList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);

scrollPane = new JScrollPane(souvenirList);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,100));

gbc3.gridx = 1;
gbc3.gridy = 1;
centerPanel.add(scrollPane, gbc3);

c.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Here is my event handler for the JList:

```
private class ListHandler implements ListSelectionListener
{
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent le)
    {
        boolean adjust = souvenirList.getValueIsAdjusting();

        if (!adjust)
        {
            //not sure if/how I should use this
            souvIndex = souvenirList.getSelectedIndices();
            //I know this is depreciated, I dont know another way 
            souvItems = souvenirList.getSelectedValues();

            for (int i = 0; i < souvItems.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(souvItems[i] + "\n");
                //my attempt to save the souvenirs to an accumlator, doesnt work right
                souvString += souvItems[i];
            }
        }
    }
}//end List handler
```

Now, i'm attempting to take what is stored in `souvString` and print it to the textArea. I have an add to cart `JButton` which compiles all the data from the GUI to give the user their overall price. I'll focus on the JList since that is what is giving me trouble. Here is the `actionEvent()` for the add to cart `JButton`:

```
else if (ae.getSource() == cartBtn)
        {
            textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            textArea.setFont(f2);
            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            textArea.setOpaque(false);
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            textArea.setEditable(false);
            //appending all the data from the GUI. souvString holds my JList selections
            textArea.setText("Team: Tigers" + "\nMeal: " + restaurant
                           + "\n\nSeats Ordered: " + seatingType
                           + "\nItems Ordered:" + "\n " + souvString);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textArea, "OrderReview",
                                         JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                                         new ImageIcon(Project7.class.getResource("/tigers.jpg")));
```

While it prints the souvenirs, weird things happen. I get a combination of `null` and **duplicate** souvenirs. I also can't figure out how to use the *parallel array* of prices that go along with the souvenirs that do print. The parallel array looks like:

```
private double[] prices = {2.0, 10.0, 15.0, 25.0, 3.0, 5.0, 9.0, 8.0, 12.0, 6.0};
```

Each price matches w/ it's corresponding souvenir from this array:

```
private String[] itemNames = {"mug","cap","tee shirt","sweat shirt","pennant","mini stick",
                            "bobblehead","paper bag","foam paw","thunderstix"};
```

I've been messing around with this for about 6 hours and can't get it to work, partially bc I don't understand `JLists` all that well, and partially bc my logic is flawed I feel. I've tried a few different approaches and those didn't work, either. If someone has some suggestions on how I could approach things differently, or even some advice/clarification on how to properly manipulate a JList, i'd be soo appreciative. I really want to understand this! Thanks again stack users :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two arrays i would create a new Class Souvenir in which you save your souvenirs with a subject and a price.

```
class Souvenir{
     String subject;
     double price;
}
```

About the JList i also dont know really much but i thought there is a method you can get a normal List from the JList Object and with this list you could work threw with the indices and put into an ArrayList of Souvenir or something like that.

This is just an idea i can't really give you an example for it so if someone else could verify this i would also be interested :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The thought did cross my mind to create a new class. Maybe i'll play around w it and see :)